# Jquery toggle one submenu only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having some minor issues while working with jquery. The code below is supposed to open the submenu list when the user clicks on the menu item. But when the user clicks on one of the menu items, it opens all other submenus as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mobile-main-menu-item-container").click(function(){
        $(".mobile-main-menu-subitem-list-container").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I have to tell that I am not surprised that it is acting like that, because the same class is used for all menu items. I just want to ask what I  have to change in the code so that only one submenu is opened. For sure, there is a better way to write the code instead of assigning different ID-s for each of them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Post a minimal working example here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `click` function, use `this` to isolate the scope of your subitem class to only children (and grandchildren, etc.) of the item clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mobile-main-menu-item-container").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".mobile-main-menu-subitem-list-container").slideToggle();
    });
});
```